# regular expression to replace '<?' by '<?php'

Tags: regex, eclipse

Hi i'm trying to find all occurences of '<?' in my php code. I use eclipse for this, and i tried to search for the folowing pattern: "<\?^[p]" in the hope this would return me all <? occrences, but not the <?php ones..

What's wrong about the regex? I thought I had figured out regular expressions, but it seams like i still have a long way to go :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Eclipse's regular expression language but I'd imagine you want this:

```
"<\?[^p]"
```

The difference is:

- `[^p]` means any character apart from `p`
- `^[p]` means the start of a new line followed by a `p`.

But you should check the manual for Eclipse to find out the exact regular expression syntax that Eclipse uses.

Comment: thanks, seems i was pretty close :) thanks for the explanation. I didn't know ^[p] did what it does

Answer (score 3):

try this: `<\?[^p]`

Answer (score 2):

If all fails, you could use a trick with no regexes: replace your `<?php` occurrences with something else (like for example `THE_PHP_TAG`), **then** search for `<?`, then replace `THE_PHP_TAG` back to `<?php`.

Answer (score 0):

### Edited

From what I understand you want to change `<?` to `<?php`. Try replacing `<\?(?!php)` with `<?php`. (This will prevent `<?php` from turning into `<?phpphp`).

Comment: This will replace `<?php` with `<?phpphp`

Comment: Then afterwards you could replace `<?phpphp` with `<?php`. ;)